Nginx load balancer throwing forbidden from moodle application server
I am facing this issue. My load balancer is throwing forbidden error upon access the moodle application server my load balancer config is this.
upstream moodle_cluster {
    ip_hash;
    server 1.2.3.4:80;
}

server {
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://moodle_cluster;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_cache_valid any 10m;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_cache_key "$host$request_uri$cookie_user";
        proxy_cache_min_uses 3;
    }
    location ~* ^/\. {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

My application server config
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 1.2.3.4;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

 location ~ ^(.+\.php)(.*)$ {
 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
 include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 include fastcgi_params;
 fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 proxy_pass_header Server;

 }
location ~* ^/\. {
        deny all;
    }  
}

and my config.php for moodle
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'mariadb';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = '5.6.7.8';
$CFG->dbname    = 'moodle';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'moodle';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'abc123';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => '3306',
  'dbsocket' => '',
  'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'https://example.com';
$CFG->dirroot   = '/var/www/html';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/usr/share/nginx/moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';


$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;


$CFG->reverseproxy = true;  
$CFG->sslproxy = true;  


// Load the setup file
require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/setup.php');

Application server error log entry is
2024/07/05 10:34:24 [error] 5828#5828: *2 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 10.0.80.12, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", host: "example.com"

Moodle work fine if I update the confg.php $CFG->wwwroot to http://1.2.3.4 and access it localy.
